# pry gem: automatically requires local gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb, pry

the REPL [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) is smart enough to automatically prefer *local* `*.gemspec` files and `./lib/` dirs when requiring a Ruby gem.

This means that, if I am working on a gem and invoke `pry` from its directory, I will be able to load the development version with just `require 'my_gemname'`. Also, any file required in the local `gemspec` will be required automatically.

`irb`, on the other hand, will only load installed gems.

Is it possible to configure `irb` to behave like `pry`?

Comment: `bundle exec irb` doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec irb
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
irb -I ./lib -r my_gem_name
```

But I imagine that there are easier ways.